# Is it possible to disable stackstorm action history if it's triggered by notification of another action

Tags: python, notifications, action

I have created an action that posts to a pubsub topic once a StackStorm action execution is completed. However, this results in a topic posting action being recorded in the StackStorm action history for every action that has **notify** section in the definition. Is there a way to disable this recording of the topic posting action in the action history through configuration?